# Calling short code with in another shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I have created a shortcode to create a block in Wordpress.

```
[block id='26' bg='#FFF' color='#000']
```

What this shortcode does is, fetch the content from page with id 26. Print it as a block in color #000 and background #FFF.

This is working fine.

Now I have another shortcode to print form.

```
[form type="xyz"]
```

Here I have some pre defined forms and depending on the type the form will be called.

Suppose I am calling `[block id='26' bg='#FFF' color='#000']` and page with `id=26` contains the form tag, it will display the form as I need. But if I am putting contents anywhere in the content area before or after the form shortcode, ie, page with `id=26` consist of contents along with form shortcode. What it does is display the shortcode for form as simple content like rest of the content.

Why it is happening like that? Any solutions to solve the issue ?

Comment: You may need to escape the very first and very last brackets of the shortcodes, read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode 
Also read about the limitations of nested shortcodes: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: It didn't helped me. I'm not looking for that.